# MIPS, dynamic array, third input overwrites the second

Tags: mips, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to create an array that takes any number of single digit integers and when the user enters -1, it stops taking more. However, the first and second numbers are stored correctly. Once I syscall for a third input, the memory address where my second number is stored is overwritten. Here is my code in MIPS.

```
    # switch to the Data segment
    .data
# global data is defined here

myArray:
    .word 256
char: 
    .word 4
sp:
    .asciiz " "
cr:
    .asciiz "\n"
error_string:
    .asciiz "\ONE DOES NOT SIMPLY WALK INTO MORDOR."
array_input:
    .asciiz "\Please type a digit. Press enter after each. End array with -1 input.\n"
neg_one:
    .asciiz "\1-"

 # switch to the Text segment
    .text
    .globl  main
main:
    # the rest of the main program goes here
    lui $s7, 0x000a  # set first half of $s7
    ori $s7, $s7, 0x312d # set $s7 to compare with beq and exit input, $s7 = -1 now.
    addi $t3, $t3, 0 # set counter for decrementing array later
    la $s1, myArray # set base address of array to $s1
    la $a0, array_input
    jal Print_string


input_loop:
    la $a0, char
    li $a1, 4
    jal Input # prompt user for digit input

    lb $t1, char
    lw $t2, char # store char from buffer into t1 (does this strip newline?)
    beq $t2, $s7, begin_sort # branch if input is equivalent to -1


    blt $t1, 48, error      # check if char is not a digit (ascii<'0')
    bgt $t1, 57, error      # check if char is not a digit (ascii>'9')
    addi $t1, $t1, -48


    sw $t1, 0($s1) # store char into array

    move $a0, $t1
    jal Print_integer # print number that was input
    la $a0, cr
    jal Print_string # print newline char

    addi $s1, $s1, 4 # increment array address
    addi $t3, $t3, 1 # increment array counter
    j input_loop # jump back up when -1 not entered

begin_sort:
    Jal Exit

.globl Input
Input: # gets a string from user into register
    addi $v0, $zero, 8
    syscall #calls for input
    jr $ra

    .globl Print_integer
Print_integer: # print the integer in register a0. Loading one into $v0 from addi makes syscall print
    addi $v0, $zero, 1
    syscall
    jr $ra

    .globl Print_string
Print_string: # print the string whose starting address is in register a0
    addi $v0, $zero, 4
    syscall 
    jr $ra

    .globl Exit
Exit: # end the program, no explicit return status
    addi $v0, $zero, 10
    syscall
    jr $ra
```

For example, I type in 8, then 5, then 3 and for my array Address 0x10010000 Value (+0) is 0x08, Value (+4) is 0x0a, Value (+8) is 0x03. Obviously (+4) is wrong and should just be 0x05. It used to be that until Jal Input did Syscall. So I think something is wrong with my address at char? I cannot enter single digits after this because my code starts getting funky. I am also aware I could use sb, but I believe I need to store these are 4 bytes for now for later manipulation. Essentially, what is overwriting my memory address at Value (+4)?Thank you so much for any input here.

Answer (score 0):

Solution?: Wow, I solved this issue by literally moving the myArray and char part below the declaration of the strings, like sp and cr. I think this is because the array space should be declared after the strings, otherwise the strings will overwrite whatever space you just declared. Then, as I adjusted my dynamic array, I ruined the strings that were stored. Weird stuff. I'd still appreciate a more full explanation.

Comment: Sorry, but, this really isn't a fix for the bug. See my answer as to why.

Answer (score 0):

You were using the `.word` directive incorrectly:

```
myArray:    .word       256
```

This does *not* define an array with 256 elements. It defines a single *scalar* word with initial value of 256. The size of the array is *only* 4 bytes.

So, after the first store into the array, you are writing past the end (i.e. *undefined behavior* in C parlance).

In your answer, you moved `myArray` to the end of the `.data` section. But, this is *not* a fix. It merely "papers over" the problem. And, *if* you have the order `myArray | char`, then the second element of `myArray` will contain garbage data.

The correct way to define an array is to use the `.space` directive. It reserves a given number of *bytes*. So, the correct definition for `myArray` would be:

```
myArray:    .space      1024
```

The `char` array had a similar problem, but you "lucked out".

There were also a few more bugs as well. Particularly, the "-1" check was weak, if it worked at all.

I've created three versions of your program. A version with the bugs annotated. A second that is cleaned up and fixed. A third that is a bit simpler, more general, and more efficient because it uses a different `syscall` to get user input.

---

Here is the annotated version [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
# switch to the Data segment
    .data
    # global data is defined here

    # NOTE/BUG: this defines a _single_ 32 bit word [with initial value of 256]
    # and _not_ an array with 256 elements
    # as it is, myArray is only 4 bytes long
myArray:    .word       256

    # NOTE/BUG: this has similar problems to above but you luck out because
    # it defines an area of length 4 by virtue of the .word directive and _not_
    # the 4
char:       .word       4

sp:         .asciiz     " "
cr:         .asciiz     "\n"
error_string:   .asciiz "\ONE DOES NOT SIMPLY WALK INTO MORDOR."
array_input:    .asciiz "\Please type a digit. Press enter after each. End array with -1 input.\n"

    # NOTE/BUG: this string is incorrect for its intended use below
    # NOTE/BUG: this isn't used
neg_one:    .asciiz     "\1-"

# switch to the Text segment
    .text
    .globl  main

    # the rest of the main program goes here
main:
    # NOTE/BUG: this is a poor way to initialize this. use "li" or "lw" instead
    # but also see below
    # NOTE/BUG: manually compensating for little endian is tedious
    lui     $s7,0x000a              # set first half of $s7
    ori     $s7,$s7,0x312d          # set $s7 to compare with beq and exit input, $s7 = -1 now.

    # NOTE/BUG: this has _no_ effect
    addi    $t3,$t3,0               # set counter for decrementing array later

    la      $s1,myArray             # set base address of array to $s1

    # NOTE/BUG: although not a bug, this should be part of the loop
    la      $a0,array_input
    jal     Print_string

input_loop:
    la      $a0,char
    li      $a1,4
    jal     Input                   # prompt user for digit input

    lb      $t1,char

    # NOTE/BUG: this is a weak way to check for -1
    lw      $t2,char                # store char from buffer into t1 (does this strip newline?)
    beq     $t2,$s7,begin_sort      # branch if input is equivalent to -1

    blt     $t1,48,error            # check if char is not a digit (ascii<'0')
    bgt     $t1,57,error            # check if char is not a digit (ascii>'9')
    addi    $t1,$t1,-48

    sw      $t1,0($s1)              # store char into array

    move    $a0,$t1
    jal     Print_integer           # print number that was input

    la      $a0,cr
    jal     Print_string            # print newline char

    addi    $s1,$s1,4               # increment array address
    addi    $t3,$t3,1               # increment array counter
    j       input_loop              # jump back up when -1 not entered

begin_sort:
    # NOTE/BUG: this _must_ be "jal" and _not_ "Jal"
    # NOTE/BUG: this should just be "j" or just move the "Exit" code here
    Jal     Exit

error:
    la      $a0,error_string
    li      $v0,4
    syscall
    j       input_loop

    .globl  Input
# gets a string from user into register
Input:
    addi    $v0,$zero,8
    syscall                         # calls for input
    jr      $ra

    .globl  Print_integer
# print the integer in register a0. Loading one into $v0 from addi makes syscall print
Print_integer:
    addi    $v0,$zero,1
    syscall
    jr      $ra

    .globl  Print_string
# print the string whose starting address is in register a0
Print_string:
    addi    $v0,$zero,4
    syscall
    jr      $ra

    .globl  Exit
# end the program, no explicit return status
Exit:
    addi    $v0,$zero,10
    syscall
    jr      $ra
```

---

Here is the cleaned up and working version. Note that the best way to do the "-1" check would be to strip the newline and implement a `strcmp` function, but I did something simpler

```
# switch to the Data segment
    .data
    # global data is defined here

myArray:    .space      1024
eArray:

char:       .space      80
echar:

sp:         .asciiz     " "
cr:         .asciiz     "\n"
error_string:   .asciiz "\ONE DOES NOT SIMPLY WALK INTO MORDOR."
array_input:    .asciiz "\Please type a digit. Press enter after each. End array with -1 input.\n"

# switch to the Text segment
    .text
    .globl  main

    # the rest of the main program goes here
main:
    la      $s1,myArray             # set base address of array to $s1
    la      $s2,eArray              # get end of array

input_loop:
    # prompt user
    la      $a0,array_input
    jal     Print_string

    # read in user's response
    # NOTE: unless you are _required_ to decode the number yourself, using
    # syscall 5 (read integer) is _much_ simpler
    la      $a0,char
    la      $a1,echar
    subu    $a1,$a1,$a0
    jal     Input                   # prompt user for digit input

    # check for -1 on input
    lb      $t2,0($a0)              # is first char "-"?
    bne     $t2,0x2D,not_negone     # no, fly
    lb      $t2,1($a0)              # is second char "1"?
    bne     $t2,0x31,not_negone     # no, fly
    lb      $t2,2($a0)              # is third char "\n"?
    beq     $t2,0x0A,begin_sort     # yes, fly

not_negone:
    lb      $t1,0($a0)
    blt     $t1,48,error            # check if char is not a digit (ascii<'0')
    bgt     $t1,57,error            # check if char is not a digit (ascii>'9')
    addi    $t1,$t1,-48

    sw      $t1,0($s1)              # store char into array

    move    $a0,$t1
    jal     Print_integer           # print number that was input

    la      $a0,cr
    jal     Print_string            # print newline char

    addi    $s1,$s1,4               # increment array address -- over edge?
    blt     $s1,$s2,input_loop      # no, loop

begin_sort:
    j       Exit

error:
    la      $a0,error_string
    li      $v0,4
    syscall
    j       input_loop

# gets a string from user into register
Input:
    li      $v0,8
    syscall                         # calls for input
    jr      $ra

# print the integer in register a0. Loading one into $v0 from addi makes syscall print
Print_integer:
    li      $v0,1
    syscall
    jr      $ra

# print the string whose starting address is in register a0
Print_string:
    li      $v0,4
    syscall
    jr      $ra

# end the program, no explicit return status
Exit:
    li      $v0,10
    syscall
```

---

The above program still suffers from a limitation in that the numbers input can only be single digits. The general solution would be to implement the equivalent of `atoi`.

But, if you're not *required* to do your own number parsing, using `syscall` #5 [read integer] is much simpler, allows any integer, and is what most mips programs use.

```
# switch to the Data segment
    .data
    # global data is defined here

myArray:    .space      1024
eArray:

sp:         .asciiz     " "
cr:         .asciiz     "\n"
error_string:   .asciiz "\ONE DOES NOT SIMPLY WALK INTO MORDOR."
array_input:    .asciiz "\Please type a number. Press enter after each. End array with -1 input.\n"

# switch to the Text segment
    .text
    .globl  main

    # the rest of the main program goes here
main:
    la      $s1,myArray             # set base address of array to $s1
    la      $s2,eArray              # get end of array

input_loop:
    # prompt user
    la      $a0,array_input
    jal     Print_string

    # read in user's response
    li      $v0,5
    syscall
    move    $t1,$v0

    # check for -1 on input
    bltz    $t1,begin_sort

    sw      $t1,0($s1)              # store char into array

    move    $a0,$t1
    jal     Print_integer           # print number that was input

    la      $a0,cr
    jal     Print_string            # print newline char

    addi    $s1,$s1,4               # increment array address -- over edge?
    blt     $s1,$s2,input_loop      # no, loop

begin_sort:
    j       Exit

error:
    la      $a0,error_string
    li      $v0,4
    syscall
    j       input_loop

# gets a string from user into register
Input:
    li      $v0,8
    syscall                         # calls for input
    jr      $ra

# print the integer in register a0. Loading one into $v0 from addi makes syscall print
Print_integer:
    li      $v0,1
    syscall
    jr      $ra

# print the string whose starting address is in register a0
Print_string:
    li      $v0,4
    syscall
    jr      $ra

# end the program, no explicit return status
Exit:
    li      $v0,10
    syscall
```

Comment: This helped my understanding tremendously. Thank you for your thorough input!